# Use of or and any in a sentence

Tags: sentence-structure

I want to combine "There is no school in my street" and "there is no hospital in my street" in one sentence.

I dont know if I can say there is no school or hospital in my street....
And if I can use isnt any instead of is no.

Comment: There is no school nor a hospital in my street

Comment: "*on* my street", unless they are in the middle of the street.

Comment: In my street there isn't a school or there isn't  a hospital.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, there is neither a school nor a hospital in my street.

I think that is the easiest way to combine them ;)